# Price Sets with discount for combinations

Tags: civievent, price-sets

Is there a way to create differentiated prices depending on the combination of selections in a price set?

E.g. if I have a two-part event in what ways can I create a price structure that gives half-off for the second part, given that you have selected the first?

The following two ways comes to mind:

- create two events and give discount codes to the participants of the first part (not good since it requires a two-phase registration and a discount code on the lose AFAIK)
- create a price structure with options first, second, both (makes it hard to count or limit number of participants for first and second half)

Other ideas?